Error to generated APK: The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0
I'm building a Flutter app in Android Studio Iguana and when generating the APK, I encounter the error:

Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.8.0, expected version is 1.6.0.

How can I resolve this? The APK is generated, but after installation, the app only shows a blank screen. If I install the app through the IDE, everything works correctly, there's no issue.
I tried to change the Kotlin version from 1.7.10 to 1.8.0 in the android/build.gradle file:
buildscript {
      ext.kotlin_version = '1.8.0'
      repositories {
          google()
          mavenCentral()
      }

      dependencies {
          classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0'
          classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
      }
  }

  allprojects {
      repositories {
          google()
          mavenCentral()
      }
  }

  rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
  subprojects {
      project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
  }
  subprojects {
      project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
  }
  
  tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
      delete rootProject.buildDir
  }


Does this answer your question? Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15

Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is an English-language site. Please post in English only. Or, if you prefer, you can post in Spanish (only!) at [es.so].
